# How to check if a combination of email id,mobile number ,name and date of birth exists in the mysql table in codeigniter 3

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

am trying to validate my form using form-validation in codeigniter 3 , its pretty good and i got validation messages and goes well. but next step is to validate the combination of email,mobile number ,name and date of birth is already exists in mysql table. please help me to sort out this problem.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi *@Sarath* please see below example -

```
 protected function YourFormValidation() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|callback_IsEmail_exist');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s  is required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and callback function is -

```
function IsEmail_exist(){//print_r($_POST);die;
        $existing_email = $this->db->where("email", $this->input->post('email'))->get('table')->num_row();
        if($existing_email != ""){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Email ID already Exist.');
             return false;
        }
    }
```

kindly do the same for your mobile and dob and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a function for get all the combination of your details and then check the field value exist or not or you can simply use created function in callback function in form-validation.

Comment: Thank you dear, but am new to here .can u please share the code what u think.

Comment: could you please show me some code...what you want to do exactly?

Comment: here is my code, 
form validation begins here
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','trim|required'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile','trim|required');
    /*here i need to check both email and mobile are exists in my table row. what am exactly going to do here*/
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
{
   $data = array(
       'email'=>form_error('email'),
       'mobile'=>form_error('mobile'),  
      );
   echo json_encode($data); 
}

Comment: Thank you so much dear....Its perfectly working @Piku, i want to check combination of multiple fields exists in my table. eg: my experience details,i can add more experiences ,so there is a chance to add already inserted details to mysql table. suppose  i added, graduation-institution-percentage to my table,then should validate the details which is already exists in table.